# Is there a version of $getJSON that doesn't use a call back?

Tags: jquery, json

I am implementing a callback for a 3rdParty javascript library and I need to return the value, but I need to get the value from the server. I need to do something like this:

```
3rdPartyObject.getCustomValue = function {
   return $.getJSON('myUrl');
}
```

getJson uses XMLHttpRequest which (I believe) has both synchronous and asynchronous behaviors, can I use the synchronouse behavior?

Comment: And why can't  you use a callback for returning/getting the value? Also, try avoiding the synchronous behavior as much as possible, since it will lock up the browser UI during its processing.

Comment: The calling code doesn't support call backs.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Looking at the jQuery source code, this is all `$.getJSON` does:

```
getJSON: function( url, data, callback ) {
    return jQuery.get(url, data, callback, "json");
},
```

And this is all `$.get` does:

```
get: function( url, data, callback, type ) {
    // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
    if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
        callback = data;
        data = null;
    }

    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: callback,
        dataType: type
    });
},
```

No black magic there. Since you need to customize stuff other than the basic `$.getJSON` functionality, you can just use the low-level `$.ajax` function and pass the [async option](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) as false:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'whatever',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { },
    data: {},
    async: false
});
```

Comment: when you pass `async: false` then how do you get the error message from `$.ajax`?

Comment: Those convenience methods are almost like presets for the $.ajax function. They're only useful if you are using those exact ajax options.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use the following before making your call:

```
$.ajaxSetup( { "async": false } );
```

I do not know the scope of the "async" property, I suspect that it is a global config. So consider whether you want to change this back to true after your synchronous call.

example:

```
3rdPartyObject.getCustomValue = function { 
    $.ajaxSetup( { "async": false } );
    var result = $.getJSON('myUrl');
    $.ajaxSetup( { "async": true } );
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var jsonObjectInstance = $.parseJSON(
    $.ajax(
        {
           url: "json_data_plz.cgi", 
           async: false, 
           dataType: 'json'
        }
    ).responseText
);
```

Answer (score 3):

But unless i am mistaken this code wouldn't work:

```
3rdPartyObject.getCustomValue = function {
  var json = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'whatever',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { },
    data: {},
    async: false
  });

return json;
}
```

As $.ajax returns the XHR object not the parsed json object.

You would need to do something more like:

```
var jsonLoader = function(url){
    this.url = url;
    this.rawData = {};
    this.getRawData();
};

jsonLoader.prototype.getRawData = function(){

    var json = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: this.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: this.getRawData(this),
        data: {},
        async: false
    });
};

jsonLoader.prototype. getRawData = function(self){
    return function(json){self.rawData = json;};
};

var loadMe = new jsonLoader("Data.json");
loadMe.rawData //has the parsed json object
```

In fact there is probably a much neater way of achieving the same

Answer (score 2):

If anybody ever has to do this in rails, I have a pretty clean way like this:

**Setup your controller like this:**

> ```
> def my_ajax_action
>
>     respond_to do |format|
>       # if you use render, you won't need a view page, the ":json =>" part takes care of all 
>       # the formatting
>       format.json { render :json => @variable_containing_json }
>     end
>
> end
> ```

**Setup the call in Javascript**

> ```
> function doAjaxWork( ) {
>
>     var ret;
>
>     $.ajax({
>         type: 'GET',
>         url: '/controller/action/param',
>         dataType: 'json',
>         complete: function(response) {
>            ret = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');
>         },
>         async: false
>     });
>
>
>     return ret;
> }
> ```

Of course, don't do this sync stuff unless you have to. Oh and while I am showing javascript with urls in it, check out [JSRoutes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes)... it's makes these really clean.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the async property is global, your method will synchronize the call.