# Coldfusion and jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

My cfc is working because I can invoke it and get the json string of data, however, my jquery ajax call gives me an error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data".

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/surveymanagement/admin/client.cfc",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        method: "GetClientsByName",
        name: "im"
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#here").html(data);
    },
    error: function(a,b,c){
        $("#here").html(a.responseText + c);
    }
});
```

When I invoke the component in another cfm page my cfc returns the string: `[{"client_id":58,"client_name":"Aimbridge"},{"client_id":104,"client_name":"IMF"}]` .

What might my problem be?

also, if I go directly to my cfc in the browser `http://domain.com/filepath/client.cfc?method=GetClientsByName&name=im`I don't get errors but it is just a white screen.  I don't know what I am supposed to be seeing when I go directly to it.

for the sake of all info here is client.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">
<cffunction name="GetClientsByName"
    access="remote"
    returntype="string" 
    hint="get clients from search term">

    <cfargument name="name" type="string" required="yes">

    <cfset var util = createObject("component", "/surveymanagement/JSONUtil")>
    <cfset var results = arrayNew(1)>
    <cfset var elem = "">

    <cfquery name="GetClientsByName" datasource="#application.dsn#">
        SELECT client_id, client_name
        FROM Clients
        WHERE client_name LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#arguments.name#%">
    </cfquery>

    <cfloop query="GetClientsByName">
        <cfset elem = structNew()>
        <cfset elem["client_id"] = GetClientsByName.client_id>
        <cfset elem["client_name"] = GetClientsByName.client_name>
        <cfset arrayAppend(results, elem)>
    </cfloop>

    <cfcontent type="application/json" reset="true">
    <cfreturn util.serializeJSON(results)>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Note: I'm using coldfusion7 so I cannot use `returnformat='json'`

application.cfc maybe something went awry here:

```
<cfcomponent 
displayname="Application"
output="true"
hint="Handle the Application">

<cfset THIS.Name = "SurveyManagement" />
<cfset THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,1,0,0) />
<cfset THIS.SessionManagement = true />
<cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = false />

<cffunction
    name="OnApplicationStart"
    access="public"
    returntype="boolean"
    output="false"
    hint="Fires when the application is first created.">

    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnSessionStart"
    access="public"
    returntype="void"
    output="false"
    hint="Fires when the session is first created.">

    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnRequestStart"
    access="public"
    returntype="boolean"
    output="false"
    hint="Fires at first part of page processing.">

    <cfargument
        name="TargetPage"
        type="string"
        required="true"
        />
    <cfparam name="variables.this_query_string" default="">
    <cfif cgi.QUERY_STRING neq "">
        <cfset variables.this_query_string="?#cgi.QUERY_STRING#">
    </cfif>
    <cfparam name="server.ThisServer" default="www4.mydomain.com">
    <cfif cgi.SERVER_PORT neq "443" or cgi.HTTP_HOST eq "www.mydomain.com">
        <cflocation url="https://#server.ThisServer##cgi.PATH_INFO##variables.this_query_string#" addtoken="no">
    </cfif>     

    <cfparam name="form.fieldnames" default="">
    <cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="i">
        <cfif Evaluate(i) neq "">
            <cfset form_value_temp=Evaluate(i)>
            <cfset form_value_temp=replace(form_value_temp,"<", "&lt;", "all")>
            <cfset form_value_temp=replace(form_value_temp,">", "&gt;", "all")>
            <cfset "form.#i#"=form_value_temp>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>    
    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnRequest"
    access="public"
    returntype="void"
    output="true"
    hint="Fires after pre page processing is complete.">

    <cfargument
        name="TargetPage"
        type="string"
        required="true"
        />

    <cfset application.dsn="SurveyManagement">
    <cfset application.title="Survey Management Site">
    <cfset application.directory="surveymanagement">
    <cfset application.cfc_data="surveymanagement">

    <cfinclude template="#ARGUMENTS.TargetPage#" />

    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnRequestEnd"
    access="public"
    returntype="void"
    output="true"
    hint="Fires after the page processing is complete.">

    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnSessionEnd"
    access="public"
    returntype="void"
    output="false"
    hint="Fires when the session is terminated.">

    <cfargument
        name="SessionScope"
        type="struct"
        required="true"
        />

    <cfargument
        name="ApplicationScope"
        type="struct"
        required="false"
        default="#StructNew()#"
        /> 

    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnApplicationEnd"
    access="public"
    returntype="void"
    output="false"
    hint="Fires when the application is terminated.">

    <cfargument
        name="ApplicationScope"
        type="struct"
        required="false"
        default="#StructNew()#"
        />

    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnError"
    access="public"
    returntype="void"
    output="true"
    hint="Fires when an exception occures that is not caught by a try/catch.">

    <cfargument name="Except" required=true/>
    <p>AN UNEXPECTED ERROR HAS OCCURRED</p>
    <p>Please consult your suggested technical support contact for assistance.</p>
    <cfif findnocase("ip address here",cgi.REMOTE_ADDR) or findnocase("ip address here",cgi.REMOTE_ADDR)>
        <cfdump var="#Except.RootCause#">
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you get the expected value when you invoke the method from a coldfusion page, assume the problem lies with your ajax call.

Comment: examine your JSON results in a development tool like chrome.  I've had issues where I've just returned text and didnt append <cfcontent  type="application/json"> infront of it.  Also, I've seen other issues when I had showdebugoutput turned on and the debugging info at the end was breaking my json.

Comment: I would take a look at exactly what the server sends back when the cfc is run through a browser (or ajax request). Earlier versions of CF tended to wrap things up as XML a lot. If you view-source in your browser, do you see anything at all? Although it's not very nice, you may be able to get away with setting output=true on your CFC method, returning nothing and using CFoutput to get your JSON to output back to the client

Comment: As Steve mentions, debug output will wreck your json. You can use CFSetting enabledebugoutput=false to disable this on pages expected to return JSON

Comment: where do I put enabledebugoutput=false?

Comment: at the top of your client.cfc  <cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">

Comment: I get nothing in the source code for my cfc in the browser. and after added the cfsetting to the top of client.cfc it is still empty

Comment: I'm not getting a response when I do the ajax call. using firebug

Comment: Although this contradicts barnyr's suggestion, you should set output=false on your cffunction (and almost always do this as a matter of course in future)

Comment: what does setting output=false do, nothing changed when I added it in

Comment: I get a new error, `unexpected end of input`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help but I'm working on working with data for angularjs and was looking at [this post](http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/json-jquery-and-coldfusion-56): Talks a bit on using CFC's w/out the need to create the JSON yourself (also demonstrates how CFMX handled json calls).

> In ColdFusion MX a cfc called directly returned wddx. To stop this, output directly instead of [using] cfreturn and append cfabort ie:
>
> ```
> <cfcontent reset="yes" /><cfoutput>#Trim(encode(qryExample))#</cfoutput><cfabort />
> ```

Comment: @Jake - Try adding the cfcontent mentioned in the link. Not sure about CF7, that fixed the error in CF9.  ie Add `<cfcontent type="application/json" reset="true">` at the very end just before the return/output. (Edit: And incorporate steve's suggestion ie `cfsetting showdebugoutput="no"`).

Comment: @Leigh I have included both of those things but I still don't get a response in firebug, and nothing comes up when i go directly to the cfc

Comment: @JakeZeitz - You should be getting *some* response in firebug. Even if it is just an error. Unless maybe you there is an Application file involved that is interfering? Also, try using the exact syntax in the link, plus the content type. ie      `<cfcontent type="application/json" reset="true">
 <cfoutput>#util.serializeJSON(results)#</cfoutput><cfabort />`

Comment: I bet there is something in the application file that is stopping it.  Because when I use cfabort I get errors. I'll edit my question to add application.cfc.

Comment: @Leigh ok I put application.cfc in the question.  I wish it was not so much to look through but maybe you can find a problem

Comment: @JakeZeitz - It is probably one of your two RequestXX methods. From what I can see, you do not actually need `OnRequest`. The application variables should be set in `OnApplicationStart`. Start by moving those variables and commenting OnRequest out.  (There are some other improvements you could make, like getting rid of `evaluate` .. but one thing at a time.)

Comment: @Leigh awesome, I'm finally getting something back although it is wddx instead of json.

Comment: (Edit fixed link) You mean it has a wddx wrapper? Are you using using [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140423/coldfusion-and-jquery-ajax/15140863#comment21319548_15140863)? Because that works for me.

Comment: ah yes, that was the problem. still had the other code in place of that. I believe the problem is fixed now. I'm just gonna accept this dudes answer since its the only one.

Comment: @Jake - Glad you got it working. You may also want to post your final code as a separate answer. Just so the next guy does not have to dig through all the comments to find the solution ;-)