# Arraylen giving occasional miscount of elements

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am having a strange problem...I have set up a cfscript for use in creating a datatables JSON object, and occasionally I am receiving an unhandled exception error "the element at position X cannot be found" The X typically is one more than my array actually has, so in my case, i have 44 elements in an array, the expression error always states "position 45 cannot be found"

heres some code

```
/* 44 total items in this array*/
aColumns = ['nd_event_group_id','nd_event_id', 'pref_mail_name',  'request_status_code', "life_gift_pledge_ob_amt", 'activity', ... ];
/* this will return 44 */
iColumnsLen = ArrayLen(aColumns);

...

savecontent variable="rc.aaData" {
    for (i=1; i <= rc.qResult.RecordCount ; i++) {
      writeOutput('{');
      for (col=1; col <= iColumnsLen; col++) {
        // the next line is what is referenced by the expression error 
        // "The element at position 45 cannot be found"
        writeOutput('"#aColumns[col]#":#SerializeJSON(rc.qResult[aColumns[col]][i])#'); 

        writeOutput((col NEQ iColumnsLen) ? ',' : '');
      }
      writeOutput('}');
      writeOutput((i NEQ rc.qResult.RecordCount ) ? ',' : '');
    }
  };
```

The strange part about this issue is that I cannot recreate the error with any precision, its a hit or miss thing that occasionally happens

this script is ran by a GET via AJAX

any ideas?

Comment: Is this code inside a shared-scope-homed CFC method, and could you be suffering from unVARed variables?

Comment: Why are you manually creating the JSON? Have you tried `serializeJSON()` on the entire query?

Comment: building off of Adam's comment you can use this to check for var'd variables. Unzip and run. It's super easy. http://varscoper.riaforge.org/

Comment: @MattBusche, does varscoper support `CFSCRIPT` yet?

Comment: @imthepitts i don't believe so, but 99% of what I deal with is tags, so I usually forget about that detail.

Comment: @imthepitts I am manually creating the JSON due to the format needed , i need it in key value pairs in the JSON object rather than data array separate from the column array

Comment: @AdamCameron, My CFC has a couple of different functions, each with an "aColumns=['one', 'two', ...];" line in it...i thought by leaving off the var on aColumns i was essentially defining it to the local function, but what youre saying is if i run one function that has that defined, the next one assumes its global?

Comment: @JayRizzi, leaving off the var is what causes it to be global to the CFC (shared by all functions). To ensure each instance of `aColumns` is thread-safe, define it within a function block and var scope it. `function doSomething(){var aColumns=['...'];}`

Comment: @JayRizzi, also, concatenating JSON strings is error prone. Instead, convert your query to an array of structures, then use `serializeJSON()` to convert to a JSON string. [Here's some code you can use.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724501/how-can-i-show-the-column-names-in-my-json-file-format-through-coldfusion/16724668#16724668)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deriving this from the comments posted, it sounds like you have variables unVARed. All function-local variables need to be declared as such, either with the `VAR` keyword, or by specifically scoping them in the `LOCAL` scope.

If you don't do this, variables are global to the CFC instance, and accordingly shared between functions. This sounds like your problem.

This is all in the docs: "[CFC variables and scope](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7dfb.html)".

Comment: indeed , i had multiple loops, and they were not thread safe, see http://www.daveshuck.com/2006/11/28/thread-safety-example-var-scope-your-loop-index-in-coldfusion-cfcs/ for more info