# How to Parse JSON Returned in ColdFusion

Tags: json, parsing, url, coldfusion, coldfusion-6

I'm sure this is a relatively simple question, but I can't seem to find a simple answer anywhere online.

I have a few lines of JSON returned by a cfhttp POST with an image URL that I'd like to parse out and display in my ColdFusion page:

```
{
    "href": "http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D_MapServer/_ags_map734a6ad322dd493e84499d78f027d841.png",
    "width": 854,
    "height": 493,
    "extent": {
        "xmin": -8285407.015562119,
        "ymin": 4944008.4197687358,
        "xmax": -8220129.7934066672,
        "ymax": 4981691.8747132765,
        "spatialReference": {
            "wkid": 102100,
            "latestWkid": 3857
        }
    },
    "scale": 288895.27714399656
}
```

How can I make "href"'s value a part of a variable in ColdFusion, and/or potentially have a button linked to downloading it?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm using ColdFusion MX - also known as version 6 - and hence why I cannot use the [DeserializeJSON listed on Adobe's page](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_43.html)

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_43.html

Comment: What have you tried? I do not mean this sarcastically, but .. a five second search on "How to Parse JSON ColdFusion" should have turned up multiple references to the `deserializeJSON`function :) Did you try it? Please post your code and any error messages. (BTW, If you are new to StackOverflow, it works a little differently than a forum. Please see the FAQ's as well: [Ask]).

Answer (score 4):

> Converts a JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) string data
>   representation into CFML data, such as a CFML structure or array.

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DeserializeJSON

Answer (score 2):

Just parsing your cfhttp result with deserializeJSON()

```
<cfset getResult = deserializeJSON(result_Variable.filecontent)>
```

and you can get the href value using "#getResult.href#"

Comment: wouldn't OP need to use result_Variable.FileContent as mentioned it is from cfhttp call?

Answer (score 2):

> I forgot to mention that I'm using ColdFusion MX

Ah, that makes a very big difference! (Unless otherwise stated in the tags, most people will assume a more recent version, like CF9+).

JSON support was not added until CF8. If you search, there are still some older udf/cfc's for handling JSON out there. For example:

- [JSONDecode](http://cflib.org/udf/jsondecode) at http://www.cflib.org says it works with MX6
- [JSONUtil.cfc](http://jsonutil.riaforge.org/) works with MX7+. It *might* work with MX6 out of the box, or with a few modifications. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123399/how-to-use-jsonutil-with-coldfusion7-and-jquery-ajax/15124500#15124500) has a description of how to encode with JSONUtil. Decoding should be equally simple. Just create an instance and invoke deserializeJSON, ie:

  ```
  <!--- not tested --->
  <cfset util = createObject("component", "path.to.JSONUtil")>
  <cfset result = util.deSerializeJSON(yourJSONString)>
  ```

That said, ColdFusion MX is a bit long in the tooth and [no longer supported](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/support-macromedia-coldfusion-mx-6.html). You should seriously consider upgrading or switching to the open source [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org/) engine.