# C#.Net Update Column in HTML Table After Page has Been Rendered

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, timer, updatepanel

I'm trying to send new values to an HTML table after a page has already been rendered. New values are sent 'x minutes' after the page has already been rendered on the client end, and are displayed in a new column in the html table.

The HTML is created with C# code with the code behind file, and initiated via a function call inside the actual html  on the aspx page.

```
htmlStr = "<tr><td>" + market[0].runners[marketCounter].runnerName + "</text></td>" + "<td>" + marketOdds[0].runners[marketCounter].lastPriceTraded.ToString() + "</td>" + "<td>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + NewValuesin10Mins()???????????????? + </td></tr>;
```

Comment: You cannot fetch data from server side once the page is been loaded, you will have to use jquery/ajax for this purpose. take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862381/getting-data-from-aspx-to-jquery-ajax

Comment: @Abdul Hannan Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to modify the client side after render, try to use the function [RegisterStartupScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.8), the script block added by the RegisterStartupScript method executes when the page finishes loading but before the page's OnLoad event is raised

```
public String GetNewKey()
{
    String _string_key = String.Empty;
    Guid _guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    foreach (char _char in Convert.ToBase64String(_guid.ToByteArray()))
    {
        _string_key += char.IsLetterOrDigit(_char) ? _char.ToString() : string.Empty;
    }
    return _string_key;
}

public void RunScript(String _script)
{
    String function = @"<script type='text/javascript'> $(function () { " + _script + " }); </script>";
    this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(_page.GetType(), Utilities.GetNewKey(), function, false);
}
```