# JQuery / JSON - Need access to the data returned from JSON outside of code block

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I was wondering if it was possible to gain access to returned JSON data outside of the JQuery getJSON method.. something like this..

```
var price = "";
$.getJSON("../JSONDeliveryPrice", null, function (data) {
  price = eval(data.price);
});
console.log(price);
```

This doesn't work tho, is there another way to gain access to price outside of that block?

Comment: You need to use syncronous request. Here is great answer hot to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933713/is-there-a-version-of-getjson-that-doesnt-use-a-call-back

Comment: Making the call synchronous is backwards. The code that handles the response must be in (or called in) the [continuation passed to `getJSON`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129/how-can-i-return-a-variable-from-a-getjson-function).

Answer (score 0):

```
var price = "";
$.getJSON("../JSONDeliveryPrice", null, function (data) {
    price = eval(data.price);
    console.log(price); // e.g. "$120", comes later
    doSomething(data); // uses the JSON data
});
console.log(price); // "", comes first
```

Comment: It will not work because your `console.log(price);` will be invoked mutch earlier then `getJSON` callback function.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you can't access the data outside of the callback function, it's just that the `console.log()` statement is executed prior to the callback being executed, so at the time the log is executed, the variable is still empty.

I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BKgBH/) to illustrate this based on the example on the jQuery site

Answer (score 0):

I was just researching a similar issue when I found this question: [Is there a version of $getJSON that doesn't use a call back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933713/is-there-a-version-of-getjson-that-doesnt-use-a-call-back)

I believe you'll need to make your call synchronously as well.