# Continue FOR loop after a function finished

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a for loop from which a function is called.In that function i have a AJAX call.After ajax finishes then it returns a value to the for loop. then only for loop has to be continued.

```
for ( var j = 0; j < req.questionId.length; j++) {

    var getanswer = getAnswers();
}

function getAnswers(){

    $.getJSON("getAnswers?question_id="+questionId,function(data){

           return "success";
    });

}
```

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of Async!!!

Comment: Clarify your question. What do you mean by "only for loop has to be continued."

Comment: Question not clear for me.

Comment: is questionid passed as a parameter to `getAnswers`?

Comment: S ofcourse.Question id is passed to the function.Only after the function returned a value then only the FOR loop continues.

Comment: your for loop cant wait until getJeson got reply

Comment: See this http://www.dariancabot.com/2010/11/09/jquery-using-ajax-inside-a-loop-and-variable-scope/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Loop of jQuery Deferreds (promises)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504921/asynchronous-loop-of-jquery-deferreds-promises)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery getJSON call is asynchronous, which means that the call is executed in the background. So you call to $.getJSON returns immediately.

You will have to provide getJSON with a "ready-function" (see the documentation), which is called when the AJAX call is returned.

Alternatively (though I would advise against it), you can force jQuery to make a synchronous AJAX call, it will wait for a reply before continuing. Check out the jQuery documentation on that.

HTH

Comment: @Raja don't make ajax synchronous.... it will block the UI for the duration of the requests... never advice it

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the call using [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to it synchronously, like this:

```
for ( var j = 0; j < req.questionId.length; j++) {

    var getanswer = getAnswers();
}

function getAnswers(){
    var result;
    $.ajax({
      url: "getAnswers?question_id="+questionId,
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
         result="success";
      }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### AJAX runs ASYNCHRONOUSLY by default

Your AJAX functions run asynchronously, so they don't interrupt the flow of your JavaScript code. What this means is that they send a request, then wait for a response and process whatever you put in your `success` function. All the while, the rest of the code keeps running.

Your best option is **probably** to take whatever you're doing with the AJAX return out of the `for` loop and pass it into the `success` parameter of your AJAX query, like this:

```
$.getJSON("getAnswers?question_id="+questionId,function(data){
    ... handle data, parse it, write to page etc ...
});
```

You **can** make AJAX run in a synchronous manner with a different call syntax, but even from here you'll struggle to get a `return` out of it:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url:      url,
    data:     data,
    success:  success,
    async:    false
});
```

Without knowing more about your code and what you're doing with the return, I can't say for certain how you should approach this, but 99 times out of 100 running an AJAX request in the way you're doing it is poor software engineering.

Comment: So as it was in the days of Lot, you offer to lead them to safety and the hordes laugh and do not listen.  But a judgement is coming, as foretold in [AJAX 25:17](http://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/1klgf6/ajax_2517/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the ajax call synchronous to use it. Use following code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        async: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're looking for is a synchronous call. Check the answer here: [getJSON Synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009755/getjson-synchronous)

By default, getJSON executes asynchronously, which means the code execution continues without waiting for a response.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$.getJSON` is asynchronous I think you need go with another approach.

Something like this this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < req.questionId.length; j++) {
    var getanswer = getAnswers();
}

function getAnswers() {
    var ret = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: "getAnswers?question_id=" + questionId,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            ret = "success";
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

This way you are forcing jQuery to run your request code synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract implementation of the solution could look like

```
getAnswers(array, complete) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        complete();
    }

    var questionId = array.shift()
    $.getJSON("getAnswers?question_id=" + questionId, function (data) {
        //do what ever you want to do with data

        //call the next question
        processQuestions(array, complete)
    });
}

getAnswers(req.questionId, function(){
    //do something when all questions are completed
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To make use of for loops you need to make your calls synchronous which is not a good practice as it looks like your page is hanged for the duration of request.

Instead make use of a recursive function, which is called as a success callback after your asynchronous call is finished.

```
// declare in global
var req.questionId = "";
var index = 0;

// declare your recursive function call
function recursiveFunction()
{
    if(index > req.questionId) return false;

    // call your ajax here using global index variable
}

// your ajax function call
function ajaxCall
{
    $.ajax({
    url: "getAnswers?question_id=" + questionId,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        ret = "success";

        // call your recursive function here
        recursiveFunction();
    }
});
}
```

Now ajax call is async and for loop is implemented by recursive calls.

Hope that helps.