# Global variable not updating after getJSON is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables

After I use the getJSON method I want to update the variable, but it doesnt seem to update from inside the .done() function.  The following console log is empty.

```
var myVar;

$.getJSON("url/path", function(data){
}).done(function(data) { 
          myVar = data; 
      });

console.log(myVar);
```

Comment: have you confirmed that the Ajax call is successful? like, `console.log(data)` right before `myVar = data;`?

Comment: Yes data retrieves an object with a responseJSON

Comment: have the console.log inside the done function and then check that myVar is getting filled our not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.getJSON is asynchronous, so the console.log call is always going to happen before the request completes and the done function is called.

Look at [getJSON Synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009755/getjson-synchronous) for doing synchronous ajax calls, although this is an anti--pattern and you should be able to do everything in the callback.

Comment: Just want to emphasize "do it in the callback", because that's what callbacks are for.