# Sorting a Jquery list alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pulling out data from a external source and the data seems to appear in a different order after every page refresh. I'm unsure if its related to my jquery or a lack of. Or if it's related to the google finance data I use to collect the data. Ideally I would like it sorted by column one alphabetically.

I'm adamant that there has to be a way to sort the array without it populating the list randomly.
JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vkf0jhpq/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
        $.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=" + gstock[i] + "&callback=?", function (response) {
            var stockInfo1 = response[0];
            var divContainer = $('*[data-symbol="' + stockInfo1.t + '"]');
            var percentStock = !isNaN(stockInfo1.c) && !isNaN(stockInfo1.l) && stockInfo1.l ? ((parseFloat(stockInfo1.c)/parseFloat(stockInfo1.l)) * 100) : undefined;
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you are doing asynchronous calls to get each stock (meaning they will run at the same time) and then appending each item when the call has been successful.

This means that each item will be appended depending on the time it takes to do the request so if the first request takes slightly longer than the second request, the second one will show before the first (which is why they seem to be in a random order).

One way to stop this and keep your order would be to [make the calls synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009755/getjson-synchronous) but I think this would make your page load time a lot longer.

Another way is to used the [`.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) so that you can use the ajax to populate a var and then once all the calls are finished you can sort the resulting var into the order you want and then append them to the document

[This is a quick example](https://jsfiddle.net/vkf0jhpq/4/) to show one way of keeping the appended items in the same order as the `gstock` var

Comment: This is a littl out of my league. :S I'll give it a shot though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cant use sync call with $.ajax() in crossdomain value. You must use this syntax

```
$.when( $.getJSON( YOUR_RESOURCE ) ).then( function( data, status, jqXHR ) {
    alert( jqXHR.status );
});
```

in according with http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

UPDATE: see this examples

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```

UPDATE2:

jsfiddle example (only console.log but work) https://jsfiddle.net/k41y4yqu/1/

Comment: Do you know hoe i could implement this into the jsfiddle? thanks!

Comment: see example with $.ajax

Comment: I hate to be a pain - but is it possible for you to implement this into the js fiddle. I've experimented but cant seem to get it working.

Comment: updated with working example (only console log for 4 items)