# Writing jQuery inside a Javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ag-grid

I have a js file called `example.js` which has a line as follows:

```
gridOptions.api.setRowData(createRowData());
```

Then there's another file `data.js` which has the `createRowData()` function that should return `ROW_DATA`. It is as follows:

```
function createRowData() {
    jQuery.getJSON('/file.txt',function(ROW_DATA){

    return ROW_DATA;

    });

}
```

But, whenever this `createRowData()` function is called from `example.js` file, it does not go inside the `jQuery` block and simply comes to the last curly bracket. Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong here??

Comment: jQuery.getJSON is asynchronous.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it does not go inside the jQuery block and simply comes to the last curly bracket."?

Comment: I'd try to `exec` ajax call `getJSON` before `setRowData` .. sort of, get the data first, then fill it in grid :)

Comment: @Dream_Cap i.e. it does not go into to execute the statement return ROW_DATA; How do I return this value??

Comment: @KresimirPendic I don't understand..

Comment: I have no idea what is intended in this code sample, but as it stands, I can see some difficulties. The `gridOptions.api.setRowData(createRowData());` statement appears to use the _result_ of the `createRowData()` function. However, being an Ajax call, there won’t be a result yet, and all you will get is `undefined`, since the function itself doesn’t return anything. If you’re getting nothing, that’s exactly what you’ve called for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you're not getting the value because getJSON is asynchronous as others have said. createRowData is retrieving the value at a later time rather than when it's called.

Here is one way to get the data with promises. I commented what's going on below:

```
function createRowData() {
    //return a new promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    jQuery.getJSON('/file.txt',function(ROW_DATA){
     //on reject, send an error
     if (ROW_DATA === null) reject("Error fetching data");
    //on resolve, send the row data
    return resolve(ROW_DATA);

    });
});
}
//use then to describe what happens after the ajax request is done
gridOptions.api.setRowData(createRowData()).then(function(rowdata){
return rowdata; //log data or error
})
```

Edit: to do a synchronous ajax request, you may be able to do something like this, referring to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009755/getjson-synchronous).

```
function createRowData() {

    $.ajax({
    url: "/file.txt'",
    async: false,
    success: function(rowdata){
    return rowdata
    }
})

}
```

To read some data to a variable like you mentioned, nodejs may help because it can handle reading input/output, and probably to a variable as well.:

Comment: Thanks but with this also it is asynchronous and I get undefined in other lines that further use the results. Is there any way to read the file to a javascript variable synchronously?

Comment: I'm getting UncaughtReferenceError: data is not defined. On the line data: data :O

Comment: I removed the line data: data and the error is gone. So, I reaches the line return rowdata and on hovering over it in the Developer Tools, I can see the data also, but it still does return this data from the function createRowData(), i.e., if I try to console.log this data where this createRowData() function is called, it gives "undefined"

Comment: Hmm, I am confused as well now. I removed the data:data.

Answer (score 2):

You get JSON from the file, pass the result to the callback function, and then return it. Return it where??

As I said, your anonymous function is a **callback** one.

Program says: When you are done reading from the file, call this function, OK?. 
While you do that, I am doing something else.

And that is what it does. The program, would go on, until the file is read, when your callback anonymous function would be called.
You can do sth like this.

```
createRowData(gridOptions.api);
// add code here if you want this code to execute even before you get the response
function createRowData(api) {
    jQuery.getJSON('/file.txt',function(ROW_DATA,api){   
    api.setRowData(ROW_DATA);   
    //Whatever else you want to do. In case you want this to be done only 
    //after the values have been read
    });
}
```

If you want to wait, for the file to be read, just, dont do anything after the function, but put it inside the callback function.

Comment: Is there any way to get the data from the file without asynchronous jQuery or Ajax? I don't want the program to go on until the file isn't fully read to a variable and then return the variable.