# Return the object via jQuery JSON request

Tags: jquery, json

How do I return the object correctly in the following jQuery example:-

```
function get_stockists() {
    $.getJSON("/stockists/ajax_get_all", function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
    });
}

var stockists = get_stockists();
console.log(stockists);
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) so you need to provide a callback method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best method is not to return, but to use a callback function:

```
function getStockists(callback) {
    $.getJSON("/stockists/ajax_get_all", callback);
}

getStockists(function(stockists) {
    console.log(stockists);
});
```

Comment: As @dfsq writes a callback is the correct way to handle this. There is another way as well, namely setting the async: false property, but this is not recommended because it blocks the UI. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933713/is-there-a-version-of-getjson-that-doesnt-use-a-call-back