# How to use a JavaScript to load and parse a static JSON file in the server

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm just starting to use javascript and json.

I need to read data (getInformation function) from a json file when processing an event in a javascript function. So I need it to be synchronic. I don't know if I am missing something in the code, or if I have to create an Request and handle the callback, or if I need to import additional javascript to use json. Because I don't know how to make it work. It doesn't work because at the end the array is empty. Any help is aprreciated.

The json file:

```
{"Users": [
    {"Name": "Jane",
        "Points": 67,
        "age": 23},
    {
        "Name": "Sam",
        "Points": 65,
        "age": 21}
]}
```

Option 1 - Function called by another function which is processing an event:

```
var getInformation = function() 
{
    var path = "./data/users.json";
    var informationArray= [];
    console.log("Loading ....");
    $.getJSON(path, function(data) 
    {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) 
        {
            informationArray.push(key + '-' + val);
        });
    }); 
    return informationArray; 
}
```

Option 2 - Function called by another function which is processing an event:

```
var getInformation = function() { 
var path = "./data/users.json";
var informationArray= [];
$.ajax({
         url: path,
         async: false,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(response) {
         $.each(response.items,
         function(item) {
         informationArray.push(item);
         });
         informationArray.push("success");
         }
         }); 
   return informationArray; }
```

I have seen the following thread and tried what is there but doens't work for me. I would like to know where is the problem in my code or if require any special configuration.

Thread: [Is there a version of $getJSON that doesn't use a call back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933713/is-there-a-version-of-getjson-that-doesnt-use-a-call-back)

Comment: what is the question? what isn't working?

Comment: When you say you are trying to parse a local file, do you mean on the client or server? If it's on the server, you need to use the URL to the file instead of a path.

Comment: Is the JSON being dynamically generated, or is it coming from a `.json` file? Because JSON is simply JavaScript, it can also be loaded in the same way a script is, and stored in local memory for interaction. Just a thought.

Comment: The question is where are the mistakes, because the array in which I intend to include the data of the json file is empty at the end of the function. I mean parse or access to the elements of the json file. It is not dynamic, is fixed information. The local json file in the server yes, how should I specify the url?  Nice, how can I load a script to store it dynamically, it doesn't causes efficiency problems?

Comment: I don't really see why the request would need to be synchronous. Server communication always should be async.

Comment: The problem is that your path needs to be a URL, you calling `./data/users.json` is not going to work. It needs to be something like `http://yoursite.com/data/users.json`

Answer (score 6):

When JavaScript is running in a browser it needs to make an AJAX request to the server to access a JSON file.  It is possible to write the AJAX request by hand but that is complex and difficult to make work in all browsers.  Instead most people use a library like jQuery.  You will need to include jQuery in your web page with something like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Then in any script tag lower in the html page you should be able to do something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "data/users.json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    $.each(response.Users, function(item) {
      informationArray.push(item);
    });
    informationArray.push("success");
  }
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I'm using

- //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
 - jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js
 
 Changing to 1.9.1/ dissable the rest funcions. Could this be the cause of having the array empty?
 
 Thanks.

Comment: Unlikely.  It might be that you are getting an empty array because your JSON object has no 'items' property.  It looks like you want the 'Users' property.

Answer (score 0):

To load a JSON file (and not require a callback) you'd use:

```
var url = 'http://yoursite.com/data/users.json';
var j = [];
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) { j = data;},
  async: false
});

alert(j.Users[0].Name);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting now this error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. By the way, is there a way to set the url dynamically?

Comment: It is not working, the j array is empty. Do I need to configure some additional library or something?

Comment: Yes, you can set the URL dynamically, you'd just make it a var like in your 'option 2' above. What URL are you using? If you enter it in a browser, the JSON should display.

Comment: As I'm testing in the workstation and I'm using  Netbeans the URL i wrote is http://localhost:8383/Project/data/users.json

Comment: Does that URL load the JSON file when you put it in firefox or whatever browser you use?

Comment: I would add `alert(data)` or `console.log(data)` inside the success function and make sure the JSON is getting pulled in there. If not, you could try changing your URL to '/Project/data/users.json' and see if that helps?

Comment: Hummm, by doing the change of the url to '/Project/data/users.json' doesn't make any difference, the access to the first object of the array is stil undefined. The problem is locating the URL, I guess I need to configure something else. But I don't know what it is. I used the URL of your dropbox of the example working and it doesn't seem to recognize it neither.

Comment: You should create a jsfiddle.net showing what's not working. If it works there you're going to have to start working from a web server instead of working locally.

Comment: @user2333683 make sure you're using async:false.