# Synchronous execution

Tags: javascript, synchronous

I have the following code

```
for (var i = 1; i<=10;  i++){
temp = "resp.items[" + (i-1).toString() + "].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url";
thumbnail = '<img src="' + eval(temp) + '">';

$("#yt_" + i.toString()).append("<a href='#'>" + thumbnail + "<br>" + resp.items[i-1].snippet.title + "</a>");

if(typeof (resp.items[i-1].contentDetails.upload) != 'undefined')
    ytid = resp.items[i-1].contentDetails.upload.videoId;
else if(typeof (resp.items[i-1].contentDetails.recommendation) != 'undefined')
    ytid = resp.items[i-1].contentDetails.recommendation.resourceId.videoId;
else
    ytid = resp.items[i-1].contentDetails.playlistItem.resourceId.videoId;

newurl = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + ytid +"?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=?";

console.log("i is " + i);

    //The following is executed after the loop finishes
$.getJSON(newurl, function (dur) {
     duration_reco = dur.data.duration;
     data[i-1] = {
                       "logo" : "logos/youtube_vsmall.png", 
                       "video_low" : "",
                       "thumb" : resp.items[i-1].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url, 
                       "title" : resp.items[i-1].snippet.title.substring(0,15) + '...' + secondsToHms(duration_reco), 
                       "author" : "koustubh", 
                       "tags" : ["1","2","3"],
                       "themes" : ["1","2","3"],
                       "link" : "playVideo?vid=" + ytid + "&service=youtube"
                     };
     });
}
```

I just found out that the `$.getJSON` function executes after completing the entire for loop. What can I do to make it wait and execute and follow the code order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a version of $getJSON that doesn't use a call back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933713/is-there-a-version-of-getjson-that-doesnt-use-a-call-back)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$.ajax({...})` so you can add  `{async:false}` in parameters 
Like

```
$.ajax({
   url : "xyz.php", 
   async : false,
   dataType : json
   success : function(data){
           //code here
   }
});
```

You can also add `{async:false}` globally.

**NOTE**: This will work with all ajax function that define on page

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

Comment: I tried to use it, but it doesnt work. It seems that the use of async:false is deprecated for jquery 1.8+ . Is there a workaraound or something else that I can try